# C# Error CS024 The type or namespace name 'Form1' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

I am fairly new to C# and I run into this error despite the number of remedies I have tried. I am using a form..

The error states:

> Error CS0246   The type or namespace name 'Form1' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

My code looks like:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace Timer2
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
```

My design code looks like this (Form1 is underlined with red):

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you rename your form?

Comment: Check designer generated code, are the partial class names are both same?

Comment: Are you getting error in the code which you shared or somewhere else? I see couple of closing braces are missing. Is it missed here only or the code also doesn't have them?

Comment: Try "clean solution" and then "rebuild all" options. That should clear out the issues with designer file.

Comment: @JericCruz I did not rename my form. It is called Form1, currently.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto both of the partial class names are the same in that code and the designer generated code.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I am getting the error in my code in that area. I just copied part of it, not the complete code. That is why some of the closing braces are missing.

Comment: @jitendragarg I cleaned the solution and rebuilt it. I tried running the program again and I had the same problem. I edited my question from earlier and I added the design code.

Comment: "I did not rename my form".  You renamed the namespace.  So now it has to be Timer2.Form1.  "are you missing a using directive".  Yes.

Comment: @HansPassant I don't think I understand, could you clarify? Do I need to change the name of the entire form name to Timer2.Form1 or just the namespace?

Answer (score 1):

As Hans Passant [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46658589/c-sharp-error-cs024-the-type-or-namespace-name-form1-could-not-be-found-are-y#comment80425680_46658589) your `Form1` class is in the `Timer2` namespace.

You can fix this by either

- use the fully qualified namespace to instaniatate `Form1`

  ```
  Application.Run(new Timer2.Form1());
  ```
- add an `using` statement for the `Timer2` namspace to your `Program` class

  ```
  namespace WindowsFormsApp1
  {
      using Timer2;

      static class Program
      {
  ```
- or change the namespace in your `Form1` class

  ```
  namespace WindowsFormsApp1
  {
      public partial class Form1 : Form
      {
  ```

  but then you have to make sure to do the same in the *Form1.Designer.cs* file also.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had:

Referenced DLL : .NET 4.6

Project : .NET 4.5

Because of the above mismatch, the 4.5 project couldn't see inside the namespace of the 4.6 DLL. I recompiled the DLL to target .NET 4.6 and I was fine.